# how to discover last id after delete and set new autoincrement mysql data line

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

i have a question, im deleting data from mysql by id in 2 tables, but on sales table i want to keep the same id after delete. And when i add a new sale keep the last deleted id.

For example, i have sale id nr 100 on delete and on create a new sale the id will be 101.
What i want is to keep 100 if i delete.

this is my model based on codeigniter:

```
public function getAllInvoiceItems($sale_id) 
    {
        $q = $this->db->get_where('sale_items', array('sale_id' => $sale_id));
        if($q->num_rows() > 0) {
            foreach (($q->result()) as $row) {
                $data[] = $row;
            }

            return $data;
        }
    }

    public function getInvoiceByID($id)
        {

            $q = $this->db->get_where('sales', array('id' => $id), 1); 
              if( $q->num_rows() > 0 )
              {
                return $q->row();
              } 

              return FALSE;

        }

        public function deleteInvoice($id) 
        {
            $inv = $this->getInvoiceByID($id);
            $warehouse_id = $inv->warehouse_id;
            $items = $this->getAllInvoiceItems($id);

            foreach($items as $item) {
                $product_id = $item->product_id;
                $item_details = $this->getProductQuantity($product_id, $warehouse_id);
                $pr_quantity = $item_details['quantity'];
                $inv_quantity = $item->quantity;
                $new_quantity = $pr_quantity + $inv_quantity;

                $this->updateQuantity($product_id, $warehouse_id, $new_quantity);

            }

            if($this->db->delete('sale_items', array('sale_id' => $id)) && $this->db->delete('sales', array('id' => $id))) {
                return true;
            }
        return FALSE;
        }
```

Comment: first, you can always overwrite the column with AI with your own (unique) value by simply stating the column in your insert statement. second, what do you do if AI is at 200 and you deleted 100? still want the next sales-item to be at 100?

Comment: Get last insertid first, then increment it by one and insert new id through query by passing 'id' field

Comment: you are correct, but, even if i delete 100 and the last is 200 the script need to autoincrement from last id: i mean if i delete 100 there will be 99 - 101 and then 200 > 201. Thanks

Comment: Is you goal a gap-less primary key? Having gaps in your primary key ID is normal.